# jQuery select item from index issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've selected an li item from a list but if I try to use function on it appear this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function


var li = $( "li" );
console.log(li[elementToGet].offset());<----ERROR
```

while

```
console.log(li[elementToGet]);
```

correctly print selected item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with;

```
$(li[elementToGet]).offset()
```

`li[elementToGet]` returns plain JavaScript element. You have to decorate it again with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `offset()` on jQuery object but indexer you used gives you `DOM` object. You need to use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the jQuery object at perticular index with jQuery object collection.

```
console.log(li.eq(elementToGet).offset());
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you like to get the first li item offset means

```
console.log(li.eq(0).offset());
```